# How I can get each source and target from doublet of doublets?

Tags: c#, links-platform

I try to use Doublets from LinksPlatform as my database engine.

I use doublet of doublets (pair of doublets):

```
using System;
using Platform.Data.Doublets;
using Platform.Data.Doublets.Memory.United.Generic;

using var links = new UnitedMemoryLinks<uint>("db.links");
var something1 = links.CreatePoint();
var something2 = links.CreatePoint();
var something3 = links.CreatePoint();
var something4 = links.CreatePoint();
var doubletOfDoublets = links.GetOrCreate(
    links.GetOrCreate(something1, something2),
    links.GetOrCreate(something3, something4)
);
Console.WriteLine(doubletOfDoublets);
```

Also, you can run this at https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Spngz

How I can get back something like (`something1`,`something2`,`something3`,`something4`) having only `doubletOfDoublets`?

Answer (score 4):

To take out the contents of your link you should use these methods:

- `links.GetLink` - gets a contents of the link (including its address)
- `links.GetSource` - gets the source address from the link's contents
- `links.GetTarget` - gets the target address from the link's contents

Please note that `links.GetLink` method is available in the `Platform.Data` namespace, so you should add it too.

Here you can see a complete example:

```cs
using System;
using Platform.Data;
using Platform.Data.Doublets;
using Platform.Data.Doublets.Memory.United.Generic;

using var links = new UnitedMemoryLinks<uint>("db.links");
var something1 = links.CreatePoint();
var something2 = links.CreatePoint();
var something3 = links.CreatePoint();
var something4 = links.CreatePoint();
var doubletOfDoublets = links.GetOrCreate(
    links.GetOrCreate(something1, something2),
    links.GetOrCreate(something3, something4)
);

var doublet = links.GetLink(doubletOfDoublets);
Console.WriteLine(doublet);

var sourceDoublet = links.GetLink(links.GetSource(doublet));
Console.WriteLine(sourceDoublet);

var targetDoublet = links.GetLink(links.GetTarget(doublet));
Console.WriteLine(targetDoublet);

var result = (
    links.GetSource(sourceDoublet),
    links.GetTarget(sourceDoublet),
    links.GetSource(targetDoublet),
    links.GetTarget(targetDoublet)
);
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result.Item1 == something1 &&
                  result.Item2 == something2 &&
                  result.Item3 == something3 &&
                  result.Item4 == something4);
```

The console output should be:

```
(7: 5->6)
(5: 1->2)
(6: 3->4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
True
```

You can run it at https://dotnetfiddle.net/qdmjcg